# Match string and return matched string with typescript

Tags: typescript

**Problem**

I have some strings containing this symbol "#" and I want to get numbers after this symbol. For example:

A) Lorem Ipsum #1234 --> #1234

B) Lorem #234 Ipsum Dolor --> #234

**What I tried**

```
    getTicketID(title: string): string {
    const re = /#(\d+)/g;
    return title.match(re); 
}
```

but it doesn't work because I can't return a string:

Type 'RegExpMatchArray' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1):

It is returning array. 
you change like this

```
getTicketID(title: string): string[] {
const re = /#(\d+)/g;
return title.match(re); 
}
```

then print the array

```
this.getTicketID(this.data).forEach(value=>console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply return the first capturing group only. Additionally you can check for a match, and return a default value in case of no match, like an empty string or whatever you prefer.

```
const s = "Lorem #234 Ipsum Dolor";

function getTicketID(title: string): string {
  const m = title.match(/#(\d+)/);
  return m ? m[1] : "default value"; 
}

console.log(getTicketID(s));
```